# Why can't I delete files from another user's Home folder even though I'm the owner?

Tags: mac, permissions

I have an external drive onto which I cloned a Macbook boot drive using SuperDuper. My username on this Mac is "jim." I also have a Mac Mini with an admin user account ("admin").

I attached the external drive to the Mac Mini. If I login to the Mac Mini as admin and drill down to `Volumes/MyExternalDrive/Users/jim/Desktop` I can't delete any files without being prompted for username/password. I checked that "admin" has rw permissions for one of the files via Get Info. The file isn't locked either. Then I changed the ownership explicitly so that "admin" is the owner. Here's the terminal output:

`-rw-------@   1 admin  staff      74727 Feb 28 11:08 picture123.jpg`

I still can't delete a file without entering credentials. Is there something special about files in another user's Home folder, even under these circumstances, even though it's a user from another machine?

Comment: The `@` at the end of the permissions output indicates that the file has extended attributes. See the answers here for removing ACLs and extended properties. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92071/file-permissions-mode-ending-in-or

Comment: Thank you @FrankThomas! Perfect.

Comment: You could just switch off permissions for the drive entirely. Get Info on the top level & there's a checkbox. Much simpler ;)

Comment: Besides the excellent answer about the extended attributes, I believe you also need write permission for the folder itself, too.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know technical reason but turning off perms entirely did not solve my problem (I had tried that before posting).

Answer (score 1):

After comments, people are making this far too fiddly. You don't need to play with ACLs or perms at all… which means you don't have to reset them if you ever go back to using it as a boot drive.

On any volume except the current boot volume, you can just switch off permissions entirely for the drive.

Get Info on the volume, unlock the padlock if locked, then check the box marked
"Ignore ownership on this volume."

Done.

[image]

Booting from that volume will then disable that option & it will behave as normal. No permissions to mess up & then have to fix again afterwards.

Comment: I had already tried that and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: You should mention what you have tried in your original question - it saves people wasting their time. You have some other issue, this should work 100%